# Salesforce Case Hierarchy Customize

Tags: case, page-layout

I am wondering if the case hierarchy list view is customizable. I have found that account hierarchy isn't customizable.

When you access the case record, right next to the case number you can see {case hierarchy} - it shows up as a list view. I want to edit it and add more columns. Is that possible? How can I do so?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this with example.

Comment: when you access the case record. right next to the case number you can see {case hierarchy} - it shows up as a list view. I want to edit it and add more columns to it. How can i accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Case Hierarchy columns are customizable. Add "Related Cases" related list on the page layout and define the columns order. The Case Hierarchy displays the column information from "Related Cases".

[image: case hierarchy]

If you do not define the "Related Cases" as related list then, it will consider the following columns by default:

> Case Number, Subject, Priority, Date/Time Opened, Status, Owner Name

Comment: @Santanu - Is this Case Hierarchy available in the Lightning view. I am struggling to find it out.

Comment: This is classic one